# Hosting a web service(Netbeans)

Tags: java, android, web-services, netbeans

I have developed a web service using netbeans. It's currently being hosted locally(localhost). I wish to connect to this web service through my android phone(and not the emulator), however when using 3G, no connection takes place.

Is there a way that I could solve this? Thanks!

Comment: You need an externally resolvable IP for your server if you want to be able to communicate with it via 3G on the phone.

Comment: In order words, do I need to host it on some server? Can't I set an external IP on my local PC?

Comment: Yes, you need to host it on a server. Wether you can have an externally accessible IP on your computer is really up to your ISP. You can always test your current ip by trying to ping it from a computer ***not*** on your home network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local networks usually employ [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). NAT prevents creating inbound connections, from internet to IPs inside NATed networks.

One way around this is to do port-forwarding on your router (if your router is the one doing the NAT).